# Set attribute of an element using webdriver + python

Tags: webdriver, python

I am trying to automate uploading an image. The uploader is a *Flash object* and using AutoIt is not an option. So I am trying to work my way around this with just webdriver.

The idea is to 'set' the value attribute of the image uploader with a link pointing to an image saved on the server. My question is, is there a method to set the attribute of an element in webdriver? I know there is one to get value (get_attribute). I am using Python/Selenium.

The input field is:

```
input type="hidden" value="" name="allImages" id="allImages"
```

and I have tried:

```
image = wd.find_element_by_id("allImages")
image.value = "http://optimusprime/uploads/b31f8a31-9d4e-49a6-b613-fb902de6a823.jpg"
```

The script runs without error, but the attribute value is not set. Can anybody please point me to the right way of setting attributes? (if there is one)

Comment: Similar for JS: [Set value of input instead of sendKeys() - selenium webdriver nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25583641/55075) at SU

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a javascript snippet as follows after reading replies from the webdriver google group:

```
wd.execute_script("document.getElementById('allImages').value = '../uploads/b31f8a31-9d4e-49a6-b613-fb902de6a823.jpg';")
```

Or as [Sam](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/1112/sam-woods) suggested in the comment:

```
image = wd.find_element_by_id("allImages")
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'foo.jpg';", image)
```

Answer from the webdriver google group:

> Using the "execute_script" method is the recommended approach in this
>   case.
>
> No, none in WebDriver, since it aims to imitate a user and a user
>   cannot set  attributes directly.

Comment: You can simplify this with this code:

image = wd.find_element_by_id("allImages")
wd.execute_script(arguments[0].value = '../uploads/b31f8a31-9d4e-49a6-b613-fb902de6a823.jpg';", image)